# DirectShow - how to determine if stream is valid (C++)

Tags: c++, directshow

I have been tasked with fixing a bug in a medical application that, among other things, can capture snapshots from intra-oral video cameras.  It uses a DirectShow SampleGrabber for this task.  I must make the disclaimer that I have not worked with DirectShow so I'm trying to get up to speed as I go.  I understand basically how the various components work together.

Anyway the bug itself is seemingly trivial but I can't figure out a workaround.  Due to the modular nature of this system, the preview window is part of a separate graph than the one created by SampleGrabber (it's a long story but this is due to legacy code to support previous devices). When the camera is active we can take snapshots and everything is happy.  When the camera is turned off, the SampleGrabber takes a dark frame but DirectShow is crashing when releasing the IAMStreamConfig interface created in the preview module (access violation). It seems like for some reason the SampleGrabber graph is somehow corrupting the graph built in the preview module. Due to the nature of this application, I cannot show any source here, but essentially here's what I want to accomplish:

I need to be able to detect if the camera is actually on or not.  The problem I'm having is that when the camera is plugged in (USB), it seems to look to the system like it is on and returning a video stream, it's just that the stream contains no real data.  When I check the state of the capture filter with the GetState method, it claims it is running; also when I check the video format properties it returns the correct properties.  It seems to me like the button on the camera simply turns on/off the camera sensor itself, but the device is still returning a blank stream when the camera is off.  Something must be different though, because it doesn't crash with the sensor is actually on and returning live video.

Does anybody have an idea of how I could determine if the stream is blank or has live video?  IE, are there any exposed interfaces or methods I could call to determine this?  I have looked through all of the various interfaces in MSDN's DirectShow documentation but haven't been able to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the callback function of your sample grabber be called, then you may consider adding a special [transform filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) between the sample grabber and the source filter (or right after the source filter), and what this transform filter does it to check whether the input sample is corrupted and block those corrupted sample.  This basically requires you to implement your own `Transform()` function:

```
HRESULT CRleFilter::Transform(IMediaSample *pSource, IMediaSample *pDest)
```

Comment: This ended up being the workable solution, though I had to put the transform filter in the preview graph, not the sample grabber graph. That way I could essentially monitor the state of the device and not even allow the user to attempt sample grabbing if the device was returning a blank stream.  Thanks again for all of your input!

Answer (score 1):

In the filter you connected after the source filter (or the earliest filter you have access to), check the [IMediaSample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it receives by the [receive()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
HRESULT Receive(IMediaSample *pSample);
```

Comment: In the sample grabber graph, the only two filters are the source and the grabber.  The grabber is an IBaseFilter, which appears to be instantiated from an ISampleGrabber instance.  I didn't see this method implemented in either object.  Do I need to query a particular interface on the grabber filter?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using ISampleGrabber, then you should set its call back function by using [ISampleGrabber::SetCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
HRESULT SetCallback(
  ISampleGrabberCB *pCallback,
  long WhichMethodToCallback
);
```

This requires you to implement a class extends [ISampleGrabberCB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  After that, you can check your received sample in function [SampleCB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd376987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
HRESULT SampleCB(
  double SampleTime,
  IMediaSample *pSample
);
```

Comment: Ah ok, I've done this, and when I inspect the IMediaSample in the callback and, for example call GetActualDataLength(), it returns a valid size. It appears to be as I suspected, it's returning a valid albeit blank video stream.  Arg.

Comment: @amnesia, exactly.  Usually the source filter implemented for the camera will keep throwing 'empty-looking' samples when the camera is not well-connected.  In this case you may either modify the source filter (which sometimes is not possible) or have a basic content check in your received sample.

Comment: Yea unfortunately the content check won't help (I just tried it), because once the threads for the capture graph are run the corruption occurs, even if I don't set any callback at all.  Somehow I've got to determine if the stream is blank before I run the graph containing the sample grabber, or I need to do it in the graph created for the preview so I can avoid creating the grabber graph altogether.

Comment: Then you can add a Transform filter between the source and your sample grabber.

Comment: First, thank you so much for your help and advice.  Second,  I have implemented the transform filter now, but before writing the code to actually inspect the data I just decided to see what would happen if the filter blocks the sample from being delivered, and what happens is the grabber just keeps waiting for a valid one to arrive.  Is there some way to abort the running filter graph from within a filter?

Comment: @amnesia: for controlling the running graph. You may pass the pointer of your [IMediaControl] to your filter, you can do either pause or stop, or stopWhenReady.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal way to tell whether camera is connected or whether the stream is blank or not. You typically have one of the following scenarios:

1. you stop receiving any samples when camera is off
2. you receive samples with all pixels zeroed out or, fully blue picture or a sort of this

Some cameras have signal loss notification, but it's model specific as well as notification method.

So in first case you just stop having callback called. And to cover the second one you need to check the frame whether it's filled with solid color entirely. When you capture raw video (uncompressed) this is a fairly simple thing to do.